# Allocator replacement check

Tags: memory-management, tbb

Im trying to replace memory allocator with libtbbmalloc_proxy.
How can I check a replacement? How to check what actually calling?
I had a source code of this program but its not mine (huge) project.

I saw /usr/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2 in gdb with `info sharedlibrary` and `info symbol malloc`.

os opensuse 13.1 library from repo

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set environment variable `TBB_VERSION=1` to see verbose information output from tbb.so and tbbmalloc.so